# How to extract 500 entries for each hour of each day from a large dataset?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a DataFrame with almost 2 million entries. I want to create a subset of this DataFrame.

In particular, what I want is to take 500 entries for each hour of each day in the dataset. The result should be saved in a new DataFrame `res`. There is a column called `datetime_event`, and `dates` is created as follows `dates = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime_event'])`.

This is my code, but it takes many hours to finish. Is it possible to optimize it a little bit, for example using `apply` and `lambda`?

```
counter = 0
current_hour = 0
res = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
for i in range(0,len(df.index)):
   hour = dates.dt.hour[i]
   if current_hour != hour:
       current_hour = hour
       counter = 0
   if counter <= 500:
       res.loc[i] = df.loc[i]
       counter += 1
```

**UPDATE:**

Sample DataFrame `df`:

```
id   datetime_event        title
11   2017-05-01T00:00:08   AAA
12   2017-05-01T00:00:08   BBB
13   2017-05-01T00:00:08   CCC
14   2017-05-01T00:00:09   BBB
15   2017-05-01T00:00:09   DDD
16   2017-05-01T01:01:00   EEE
17   2017-05-01T01:01:01   EEE
18   2017-05-01T01:01:09   DDD
19   2017-05-01T01:01:09   EEE
20   2017-05-01T01:01:11   EEE
```

I would like to get a subset `res` that would contain first N entries from each hour (for example, first 3 entries like in the example below):

```
id   datetime_event        title
11   2017-05-01T00:00:08   AAA
12   2017-05-01T00:00:08   BBB
13   2017-05-01T00:00:08   CCC
16   2017-05-01T01:01:00   EEE
17   2017-05-01T01:01:01   EEE
18   2017-05-01T01:01:09   DDD
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data and desired output e.g. for 3 entries, not 500 for verifiable sample?

Comment: @jezrael: Please check my update. The issue consists in the long computational time when using `for` loop, and I want to find some solution that could decrease this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df = df[df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['datetime_event']).dt.floor('H')).cumcount() < 3]

print (df)
   id       datetime_event title
0  11  2017-05-01T00:00:08   AAA
1  12  2017-05-01T00:00:08   BBB
2  13  2017-05-01T00:00:08   CCC
5  16  2017-05-01T01:01:00   EEE
6  17  2017-05-01T01:01:01   EEE
7  18  2017-05-01T01:01:09   DDD
```

**Timings**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime_event':pd.date_range('2000-01-01', freq='2T', periods=10**5)})

df['val'] = np.arange(len(df))


In [29]: %timeit df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['datetime_event']).dt.floor('H')).head(3)
100 loops, best of 3: 15.8 ms per loop

In [30]: %timeit df[df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['datetime_event']).dt.floor('H')).cumcount() < 3]
100 loops, best of 3: 15.8 ms per loop
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime_event':pd.date_range('2000-01-01', freq='2S', periods=10**5)})

df['val'] = np.arange(len(df))

In [33]: %timeit df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['datetime_event']).dt.floor('H')).head(3)
100 loops, best of 3: 14.1 ms per loop

In [34]: %timeit df[df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['datetime_event']).dt.floor('H')).cumcount() < 3]
100 loops, best of 3: 14.5 ms per loop
```

Comment: Good idea, I try it.

Comment: Though both solutions are nice, I prefer this one, because in this case I do not need to create a new column `val`.

Comment: @Dinosaurius, please check UPDATE section in my answer - i didn't add a new column there... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [22]: df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['datetime_event']).dt.floor('H')).head(3)
Out[22]:
   id       datetime_event title
0  11  2017-05-01T00:00:08   AAA
1  12  2017-05-01T00:00:08   BBB
2  13  2017-05-01T00:00:08   CCC
5  16  2017-05-01T01:01:00   EEE
6  17  2017-05-01T01:01:01   EEE
7  18  2017-05-01T01:01:09   DDD
```

Comment: The update is nice. Unfortunately, I cannot accept two answers:))) Thank you very much.

Comment: @Dinosaurius, sure, no prob :)